# How can I view my test classes debug logs of an ant deploy

Tags: unit-test, ant, failing-tests, debug-logs

I have about 20 classes that I deploy to production via ant.

Some of my test classes fail.

I want to view the debug logs but I cannot find the way to look at the logs of my ant deployment.

Any help on how to do that?

Comment: try running command `ant -v` while validation where `v` stands for verbose (Debug Level).

Comment: Thanks @RohitMourya I have done that, now I can see logs, but only from triggers and not from the classes that my tests triggered, do you know how can I see my classes logs?

Comment: This should have solved your problem. However, you can also look into developer console/ Setup->Debug logs; I'm not sure about this. Give it a try.

Comment: I have tried to find all of this in the debug logs but couldn't - not in the dev console and not in the setup/debug logs page, although over there you need to add a user to follow, so maybe this has something to define. Th -v worked as now I see logs but not of all the classes - I see only trigger logs

Comment: you'll need to turn on the debug logs for the user the deploy is running as.  Additionally, if you don't need full debug logs and really just need some extra info, over in setup you can see deployment status and get some info there.